# Can I ask which martial art is the most popular?

Tags: discussion

Is it possible to ask this kind of questions on Martial Arts SE? I want to investigate which martial art is the most popular at the moment. How can I start investigating and which factors should I consider? Are there sources that already handled this topic?

Comment: It's broad and could be varied across locations and also open to opinions. Popularity can change over time too. Could you nail it down more specifically about what it is you want to know about popularity? I don't think asking how to investigate this is that bad a question though.

Comment: Like @MattChan said, popularity of a martial art can be different overtime as well as depending on which country/region you are at. a good example in China, Sanda is practically a national and everyone does it while in people do muay thai. 

With the recent release of the IP Man series, many people are flooding the Wing Tsun schools. This happened previously with Karate(The Karate Kid), Aikido (steven seagal's movies) and etc.

What you should consider is which art is more suitable for your personality/body build & purpose.

Comment: I agree with you both.

Answer (score 1):

I think asking for references to studies regarding the population of individuals who study particular martial arts would be fair game.

However, I would take care in the wording to ensure everyone understands that you are asking for references on statistics, not personal opinion.